# Hetzner script, configuring SSD + RAID1 image installation

Tags: linux, raid, lvm, mount, hetzner

I am trying to figure out how to set this configuration on my Hetzner server.

The hetzner installimage script provides a default configuration (with comments: http://pastebin.com/tBqezpFn):

```
# Onboard: Corsair CSSD-F120GB2
DRIVE1 /dev/sda
# Onboard: ST33000651AS
DRIVE2 /dev/sdb
# Onboard: ST33000651AS
DRIVE3 /dev/sdc
SWRAID 1
SWRAIDLEVEL 5
BOOTLOADER grub
HOSTNAME Debian-78-wheezy-64-minimal
PART swap swap 8G
PART /boot ext3 512M
PART / ext4 all
IMAGE //root/.oldroot/nfs/images/Debian-78-wheezy-64-minimal.tar.gz
```

and I would set up /dev/sda1 as root mount point, and a RAID1 with /dev/sdb & /dev/sdc as /home mount point.

To do this, I would comment out the SSD and set the two hdds as DRIVE1 & DRIVE2, and set SWRAIDLEVEL to 1.

At this point I haven't understand how (check the pastebin with comments if you're unfamiliar with the script) to set the mount points.

Comment: If I got it right, you should install system on a SSD drive, then create raid1 manually and edit FSTAB to set HOME mount point.

Comment: This is what I did, finally. Installed just on /dev/sda with script and manually configured SWRAID later. Thanks everyone.

Comment: That is exactly what I suggested. It is the only way on hetzner currently.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you can do this with Hetzner's automatic install script.
AFAIK any SWRAID configuration on this script will use the first disks which is not what you want.

Personally I would simply install the OS on sda without configuring any RAID.

Then after installation is complete and the OS booted I would manually create the partitions and RAID1 on sdb & sdc.

Here's a tutorial on how to do this: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-creating-software-raid-one-arrays/